# What are some good screencapturing applications?

Tags: software-recommendation, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Creating a professional looking screencast?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11358/creating-a-professional-looking-screencast)
>   [Recommendations for video editing + screen capturing software](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16834/recommendations-for-video-editing-screen-capturing-software)
>   [Camtasia, Screenflow, or “Other?”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/camtasia-screenflow-or-other)

What are some good screencapturing applications for OS X? I am specifically looking for an application that records in HD video. I have used QT Player X, but I'm wondering if there are some alternatives out there.

Comment: Might I suggest that in the future, you do a search before you ask questions? This is a duplicate of previously asked questions, and I've noticed that you often ask questions that are duplicates.

Comment: @Negrino I did search. Where's the duplicate?

Comment: @daviesgeek - Your search-fu needs some work… [This would have been a good place to start looking](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-capture), for instance.

Comment: @Dori I am so sorry!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm partial to [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/). It works well, it's easy to use, and it's good for both capturing the screen, capturing audio (or even video via FaceTime camera) of you narrating the screencast, and can handle mixing the different sources of input. At $99, it isn't cheap, but it does work well. I use it for demo videos for my students.

Answer (score 0):

if you not want to buy software in lion you can use preview to capture screen in menu file "Take Screen Shot" or use command + shift +3 (full screen) / command + shift + (select area) and command + shift + 4 + spacebar to capture active windows screen

Comment: These are just stills, right? @daviesgeek said he was looking for video

Comment: Davies is asking for video

Answer (score 0):

[Screeny](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/screeny/id440991524?mt=12) is another utility that may be of interest to you and comes in substantially cheaper than many in the category of screen capture apps. The full range of features includes:

- Screeny is a Menu Bar app and a very simple & powerful tool.
- Record Video & Snap Images of your screen at any size.
- Cloud App support.

  - Optionally have Images & Video automatically uploaded to your Cloud App account!
  - Optionally compress videos in the highest quality H.264 before uploading to Cloud App to save on file size.
  - View upload & compression progress for Cloud App uploads in the Menu Bar drop down.
- Videos saved down at highest possible quality, and can be exported for web, etc. using Quicktime.
- Multiple Video Frame Rates.

  - Record in 60, 30, 20, or 15 Frames Per Second.
  - Lower frame rates improve recording quality for slower machines, or when not much CPU power is available at the time of recording.
- Optionally capture Audio from your computer's microphone when recording video.
- Optionally capture System Audio.

  - Requires a 3rd party plugin.
  - Instructions on the Screeny Support site.
- Customizable keyboard shortcuts for all recording actions.
- Set your recording canvas size by entering a specific pixel dimension or by choosing some handy pre-set dimensions or by clicking, dragging & expanding the recording canvas.

You can also visit their [website](http://screenyapp.com/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

## [iShowU](http://shinywhitebox.com/ishowu-v1/)

is an alternative. I did not personally use it but, I saw some screencasts made with it.